# How does the .elf file for powerpc work in Qemu?

Tags: qemu, powerpc

As a result of my research, I learned that –kernel can only load multiboot1 or Linux kernel without disk image. But I want to run a .elf file without a multiboot or linux kernel.The parameters and output are as follows.

```
qemu-system-ppc -cpu mpc8572 -d guest_errors,unimp -M ppce500 -nographic -kernel RTOS.elf -m 1G 


invalid/unsupported opcode: 00 - 00 - 00 - 00 (00000000) 00000000 0
```

Although there is no multiboot kernel (https://github.com/ara4711/ppc_hw) this example works successfully with the –kernel option. But for the .elf I have, the result is unsuccessful.

Is it possible to run this .elf file in qemu?

Comment: Do you want something like https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation which allows to run foreign-arch binaries (in this case your powerpc elf)?